# How to handle button Click event which is located in listview EmptyDa

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview EmptyDataTemplate in which i have a cancel button. When I search some item in listview and item is not found then i bound listview with null. and now my EmptyDataTemplate displayed with a custom UI which have a linkbutton. Now I want to repopulate my listview on linkbutton click.Please tell me how to achieve this.

```
 <EmptyDataTemplate>
<div style="width:100%; text-align:right;" class="alertErrmsg" id="divMsg">
<div class="norecord_box"><br><br> <img border="0" usemap="#Map" src="../images/nrf.png">
<br><br><h1>No Record Found</h1><br> <br>
<div><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="searchcancel"  CssClass="createbutton" OnClick="searchcancel_Click" Text="cancel"></asp:LinkButton></div><br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: there is no online solution about this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to repopulate my listview on linhbutton click

Well, you have your event handler. So take the code that populates your listview originally (perhaps in PageLoad?). Refactor that into a separate method and call that method in your page load and also in the **`searchcancel_Click`** handler.

Comment: I add a Breakpoint to searchcancel_Click code block but it does not triggered.

Comment: The link is there? Are you sure you are not somewhere else removing the OnClick searchcancel_Click

Comment: @plean i am sure sir... actually postback occur but my eventhandler not triggered..

Comment: Can you isolated it to the EmptyDataTemplate: what if you move the code outside the EmptyDataTemplate and onto the page? Same result?

Comment: @plean no sir.. after moving it from EmptyDataTemplate it worked but inside EmptyDataTemplate it doesn't??